# Javascript, same code, different buttons error

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, input, range

Something weird is happening, i have a function that should process all buttons in the same way, but it doesn't. I can't find the error.
Only the third button works right. The input range div moves and places itself on the other side so you can toggle it.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/johnhope/ybzhshtn/1/)

i suppose it's a problem with the left animate or with CSS variables.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#reak00').change(saveSettings);
    $('#rebk00').change(saveSettings);  
    $('#reck00').change(saveSettings);     
    loadSettings();
    });   
    function loadSettings() {
    $('#reak00').val(localStorage.reak00);
    $('#rebk00').val(localStorage.rebk00);  
    $('#reck00').val(localStorage.reck00);      
    }
    
    
    function saveSettings() {
    localStorage.reak00 = $('#reak00').val();
    localStorage.rebk00 = $('#rebk00').val();  
    localStorage.reck00 = $('#reck00').val();    
    }
 
 
 
 
     var assignHandlers = function(selectorOne, selectorTwo, selectorThree){
        return function(){

            var distanza = $(selectorOne);
            $(selectorTwo).on('focus change', function(){
                var posizione = $(this).val(); 
                distanza.css({left:posizione}).animate({
                  'left': (posizione *100 / 200)
                });
            });


            $(selectorTwo).on('focus change', function(){
                    r = $(selectorTwo).val().toString(16);
                    var opacityRed = r / 100;        
                    $( selectorThree ).css("background-color", "rgba(255,255,255," + opacityRed + ")");
                    $( selectorThree ).css("box-shadow", "0 0 25px rgba(255,127,50," + opacityRed + ")");

            });
        };
      };
    $(document).ready( assignHandlers('.fkbtn01', '.reak00', "#fbs01") );
    $(document).ready( assignHandlers('.fkbtn02', '.rebk00', "#fbs02") );
    $(document).ready( assignHandlers('.fkbtn03', '.reck00', "#fbs03") );
    
    $(function(){
        document.getElementById('reak00').focus();
        document.getElementById('rebk00').focus();
        document.getElementById('reck00').focus();
    });
```

```css
    #recorder01 { position: absolute; visibility: visible; left: 131px; top: 50px; z-index: 150; }
    #recorder02 { position: absolute; visibility: visible; left: 131px; top: 104px; z-index: 150; }
    #recorder03 { position: absolute; visibility: visible; left: 131px; top: 158px; z-index: 150; }
    #recarea01 { position: absolute; visibility: visible; left: 180px; top: 50px; z-index: 100; }
    #recarea02 { position: absolute; visibility: visible; left: 180px; top: 104px; z-index: 100; }
    #recarea03 { position: absolute; visibility: visible; left: 180px; top: 158px; z-index: 100; }
    #offarea01 { position: absolute; visibility: visible; left: 180px; top: 50px; z-index: 50; }
    #offarea02 { position: absolute; visibility: visible; left: 180px; top: 104px; z-index: 50; }
    #offarea03 { position: absolute; visibility: visible; left: 180px; top: 158px; z-index: 50; }
    input[type=range] {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      width: 100%;
      height:100%;
     }   
      input:focus, textarea:focus {
        outline: none;
    }
      
     .fkbtn01, .fkbtn02, .fkbtn03 {
            position: absolute;
            width: 50px;
            opacity: 0.4;
        }
        
      .fkbtn01, .fkbtn02, .fkbtn03 input {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      width: 100px; 
      height: 50px;  
      }  
      .fkbtn01, .fkbtn02, .fkbtn03 input::-webkit-slider-thumb { 
     
      height:50px;
      width: 50px;
       } 
    
    .fakblsfondo {
      background-color: ccc;
      height:50px;
      width: 50px;
      border-radius:4px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 25px #FF9900;
    
    }
    
    .offb {
      background-color: grey;
      height:50px;
      width: 50px;
      border-radius:4px;
      opacity: 1 ;
    
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <div id="recorder01">
    <div class="fkbtn01">
    <input type="range" class="reak00" id="reak00" min="0" max="100" step="100"  />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="recarea01">
    <div class="fakblsfondo" id="fbs01" ></div>
    </div>   
    <div id="recorder02">
    <div class="fkbtn02">
    <input type="range" class="rebk00" id="rebk00" min="0" max="100" step="100"  />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="recarea02">
    <div class="fakblsfondo" id="fbs02" ></div>
    </div>     
    <div id="recorder03">
    <div class="fkbtn03">
    <input type="range" class="reck00" id="reck00" min="0" max="100" step="100"  />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="recarea03">
    <div class="fakblsfondo" id="fbs03" ></div>
    </div>  
    
    <div id="offarea01">
    <div class="offb" ></div>
    </div>   
    <div id="offarea02">
    <div class="offb" ></div>
    </div>   
    <div id="offarea03">
    <div class="offb" ></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Help us help you. What is the desired result? What is the current behavior? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: The third button is working right, but the first and second don't. I did let some opacity to see the behavior.

Comment: Please define "working right" and "don't". We're not mind readers. What is supposed to happen and what is actually happening?

Comment: right: The input range div moves left-right in order to place itself jut under your mouse on the opposite side of the range. This way, you can eventually toggle 2 different values, like a switch. see the fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.fkbtn01, .fkbtn02, .fkbtn03 input {
.fkbtn01, .fkbtn02, .fkbtn03 input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
```

When you do css selectors like this, the input part at the end does not apply to all the fields that came before it.  Only the immediately previous one.  As such these rules are only affecting the inputs associated with fkbtn03.

Example

```
.fkbtn01 input, .fkbtn02 input, .fkbtn03 input {
.fkbtn01 input::-webkit-slider-thumb, .fkbtn02 input::-webkit-slider-thumb, .fkbtn03 input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
```

Comment: Oh, i see. Is there a workaround or the full code has to be trashed?